# Optimal way to find shared elements between combination pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations

I have a list of ordered items of type A, who each contain a subset from a list of items B. For each pair of items in A, I would like to find the number of items B that they share (intersect).

For example, if I have this data:

```
A1 : B1  
A2 : B1 B2 B3  
A3 : B1
```

Then I would get the following result:

```
A1, A2 : 1  
A1, A3 : 1  
A2, A3 : 1
```

The problem I'm having is making the algorithm efficient. The size of my dataset is about 8.4K items of type A. This means 8.4K choose 2 = 35275800 combinations. The algorithm I'm using is simply going through each combination pair and doing a set intersection.

The gist of what I have so far is below. I am storing the counts as a key in a map, with the value as a vector of A pairs. I'm using a graph data structure to store the data, but the only 'graph' operation I'm using is get_neighbors() which returns the B subset for an item from A. I happen to know that the elements in the graph are ordered from index 0 to 8.4K.

```
void get_overlap(Graph& g, map<int, vector<A_pair> >& overlap) {

map<int, vector<A_pair> >::iterator it;

EdgeList el_i, el_j;
set<int> intersect;

size_t i, j;

VertexList vl = g.vertices();

for (i = 0; i < vl.size()-1; i++) {
    el_i = g.get_neighbors(i);

    for (j = i+1; j < vl.size(); j++) {
        el_j = g.get_neighbors(j);

        set_intersection(el_i.begin(), el_i.end(), el_j.begin(), el_j.end(), inserter(intersect, intersect.begin()));
        int num_overlap = intersect.size();

        it = overlap.find(num_overlap);
        if (it == overlap.end()) {
            vector<A_pair> temp;
            temp.push_back(A_pair(i, j));
            overlap.insert(pair<int, vector<A_pair> >(num_overlap, temp));
        }
        else {
            vector<A_pair> temp = it->second;
            temp.push_back(A_pair(i, j));
            overlap[num_overlap] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have been running this program for nearly 24 hours, and the ith element in the for loop has reached iteration 250 (I'm printing each i to a log file). This, of course, is a long way from 8.4K (although I know as iterations go on, the number of comparisons will shorten since j = i +1). Is there a more optimal approach?

Edit: To be clear, the goal here is ultimately to find the top k overlapped pairs.

Edit 2: Thanks to @Beta and others for pointing out optimizations. In particular, updating the map directly (instead of copying its contents and resetting the map value) drastically improved the performance. It now runs in a matter of seconds.

Comment: What's the point of the `else` block? You seem to want to keep the *last* pair that generated a given overlap number. Why not just reverse the order, keep the *first* one, and save a lot of unnecessary grinding?

Comment: The if/else block is for inserting the count for the pair in a map. So, if that count (key) does not exist in the map, I create a new list, add the pair to it, and insert into the map. Else, I retrieve the list of pairs already associated with that key, and append the pair I just generated.

Comment: Also, g.get_neighbors() retrieves a set of integers. I'm thinking to use presorted vectors instead. I imagine set_interaction() on vectors would be a faster operation than on sets.

Comment: Oh, I see, my mistake... But... in that case, aren't you doing a lot of copying of big vectors unnecessarily? Wouldn't it be better to say `it->second.push_back(A_pair(i,j))`?

Comment: I agree with Beta on this, `it->second.push_back(A_pair(i,j))` seems a lot more efficient

Comment: How many B's are there, and what is the average number of neighbours?

Comment: @Beta Ok I see. I will also make this change. A colleague of mine had mentioned about using bit operations instead of set_intersection, but hopefully this change along with using vectors will improve the speed enough so I won't need to bother with that.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Actually, the graph is very sparse. Many nodes don't have any neighbors (come to think of it, I could probably do some check like if at least one neighbor list is empty, skip the intersection operation).

Comment: @Aaron - yes I was wondering about bit intersections, but if your graph is sparse it is probably not so useful.  I think Beta's idea will make a huge improvement so try that first.

Comment: What are you going to do with those pairs? Do you really need them all? Or will there be some processing afterwards? If you really need them all, you'll have to handle the pain of looping over them all, no cleverness possible. But I highly doubt anyone is interested in all 35 billion pairs...

Comment: @Heuster The goal is to find the top k overlapped pairs.

Comment: @Aaron That is the most crucial part of your question, so please add it. You cannot expect anyone to propose a fast algorithm if you leave that out. Generating all possible pairs will probably not be needed.

Comment: @Beta I think that change was the most significant improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to make things faster by pre-computing a reverse (edge-to-vertex) map. This would allow you to avoid the set_intersection call, which performs a bunch of costly set insertions. I am missing some declarations to make fully functional code, but hopefully you will get the idea. I am assuming that EdgeList is some sort of int vector:

```
void get_overlap(Graph& g, map<int, vector<A_pair> >& overlap) {

map<int, vector<A_pair> >::iterator it;



EdgeList el_i, el_j;
set<int> intersect;

size_t i, j;

VertexList vl = g.vertices();

// compute reverse map
map<int, set<int>> reverseMap;
for (i = 0; i < vl.size()-1; i++) {
    el_i = g.get_neighbors(i);
    for (auto e : el_i) {
        const auto findIt = reverseMap.find(e);
        if (end(reverseMap) == findIt) {
            reverseMap.emplace(e, set<int>({i})));
        } else {
            findIt->second.insert(i);
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < vl.size()-1; i++) {
    el_i = g.get_neighbors(i);

    for (j = i+1; j < vl.size(); j++) {
        el_j = g.get_neighbors(j);

        int num_overlap = 0;
        for (auto e: el_i) {
            auto findIt = reverseMap.find(e);
            if (end(reverseMap) != findIt) {
                if (findIt->second.count(j) > 0) {
                    ++num_overlap;
                }
            }
        }

        it = overlap.find(num_overlap);
        if (it == overlap.end()) {
            overlap.emplace(num_overlap, vector<A_pair>({ A_pair(i, j) }));
        }
        else {
            it->second.push_back(A_pair(i,j));
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't do the precise performance analysis, but inside the double loop, you replace "At most 4N comparisons" + some costly set insertions (from set_intersection) with N*log(M)*log(E) comparisons, where N is the average number of edge per vertex, and M is the average number of vertex per edge, and E is the number of edges, so it could be beneficial depending on your data set.
Also, if your edge indexes are compact, then you can use a simplae vector rather than a map to represent the reverse map, which removed the log(E) performance cost.

One question, though. Since you're talking about vertices and edges, don't you have the additional constraint that edges always have 2 vertices ? This could simplify some computations.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting idea. I'm a bit confused near the part `if (findIt->second.count(j) > 0)`. From what I see, findIt->second is the vector<int> of A items associated with a particular B, right? Then wouldn't you use something like find() on that vector to check if j is included?

Comment: findIt->second is contains pretty much what you just said, except it's a set<int>, not a vector<int>, to make lookup faster. I used `set<int>::count(int)` rather than `set<int>::find(int)` because I find that it expresses the intent of a "contains ?" test better, but that's largely arbitrary.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I didn't see it was a set. Even though my program runs fast enough now (with the changes from the comments above), I'm marking this as an answer since it should, theoretically, be faster.